# Rails rack conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I got a rack conflict error after installing ruby and rails on OSX.

```
sudo rails new test -T
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1990:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate actionpack-3.2.13, because rack-1.5.2 conflicts with rack (~> 1.4.5) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1163:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1199:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1185:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1185:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1167:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:48:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:
`gem uninstall rack`

```
Select gem to uninstall:
1. rack-1.4.5
2. rack-1.5.2
3. All versions 
>2
Successfully uninstalled rack-1.5.2
```

Comment: I now no longer have any version of rack installed. how would i install version 1.4.5?

Comment: *** LOCAL GEMS ***
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)

Comment: please install rack using:---  gem install rack -v 1.4.5

Comment: WORKING!! Thank you, whats up with the latest Rack version then?!